# Python pip install error shlex.py

Tags: python, arch-linux, pip, manjaro

Can't install anything via `pip install` or `pip3 install`, it throws the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in main                                                                      
    status = self.run(options, args)                                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 255, in run                                                                       
    with self._build_session(options) as session:                                 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 93, in _build_session                                                             
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 344, in __init__                                                                          
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()                                     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 108, in user_agent                                                                        
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),                  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution                                                                                
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)                     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distro.py", line 677, in linux_distribution                                                                                
    self.version(),                                                               
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distro.py", line 737, in version         
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),                                             
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distro.py", line 899, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distro.py", line 552, in __get__         
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)                                
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distro.py", line 1012, in _lsb_release_info                                                                                
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output              
    **kwargs).stdout                                                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 145, in __new__   
    process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/run/__init__.py", line 121, in create_process                                                                              
    shlex.split(command),                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 305, in split                          
    return list(lex)                                                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 295, in __next__                       
    token = self.get_token()                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 105, in get_token                      
    raw = self.read_token()                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 136, in read_token                     
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)                                              
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I`m on Manjaro Linux, using KDE. Some more info, if needed:

```
NAME="Manjaro Linux"
ID=manjaro
ID_LIKE=arch
PRETTY_NAME="Manjaro Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="1;32"
HOME_URL="https://www.manjaro.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.manjaro.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.manjaro.org/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching on internet And i found the following useful information.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-Linux/

The information suggest for correct pip function to have some additional requierements. Additionally dictates that get-pip.py does not coordinate with some operative systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python installation is borked because of the `subprocess.run` package. If you have installed `subprocess.run` via `pip`, uninstall it:

```
sudo pip3.7 uninstall subprocess.run
```

If you didn't install it explicitly, find out what package owns the code:

```
pacman -Qo /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/run/__init__.py
```

then uninstall it:

```
sudo pacman -R pkgname
```

Related issue with the `subprocess.run` package (unresolved): https://github.com/xando/subprocess.run/issues/5